# What are load generator machines?

Tags: networking, webserver

I am reading a book: `HTTP: The Definitive Guide`.

It says:

> If your server doesn’t get faster than about 500 transactions/sec,
>   make sure you are not experiencing TIME_WAIT port exhaustion. You can
>   fix this problem by using more client **load-generator machines** or
>   making sure the client and server rotate through several virtual IP
>   addresses to add more connection combinations.

I am software developer who don't have much knowledge about hardware. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What are load generator machines?

They are machines running scripts that are used to generate loads for web servers during load (performance) testing to ensure that the web servers have adequate capacity when put in production.

> Load testing lets you measure your website's quality of service (QOS) performance based on actual customer behavior. Nearly all the load testing tools and frame-works follow the classical load testing paradigm: when customers visit your web site, a script recorder records the communication and then creates related interaction scripts.
>
> A **load generator** tries to replay the recorded scripts, which could possibly be modified with different test parameters before replay. In the replay procedure, both the hardware and software statistics will be monitored and collected by the conductor, these statistics include the CPU, memory, disk IO of the physical servers and the response time, throughput of the system under test (SUT), etc. And at last, all these statistics will be analyzed and a load testing report will be generated.

Source [Load testing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing)